# Vmware Server and Subversion issue

Tags: svn

i am having some issue with subversion installed in a windows server 2003 virtual machine under vmware server.

The issue is as follows :

- After start the windows server virtual machine i was able to checkout files and commit files for like half to 1 hour
- Then i encounter the following error when trying to commit files :
  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
- But i am still able to checkout files. At this point of time i try accessing my windows server virtual machine through the vmware console but it was very slow. I checked the cpu / memory usage and nothing was unusal.
- I also used some malware checker to remove like 10 to 11 malwares. But the same issue still occur no matter how many times i check and restart the server.

I am thinking of doing a windows update. But i really hope experts here can shed some light on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There should be absolutely no malware in your server. If you have some (as you indicated that you do), the best thing to do is make a copy of your Subversion repository, then set up a new server instance *without* malware. Then restore your Subversion repository into the new server image.